# Weka Vote: how to tune individual classifier

Tags: weka, vote

Hi, I am using weka.classifier.meta. Vote. I am combining three classifiers, one of them is SMO. I want to know how can I specifically set the parameter values for SMO. Is there a way to do this using the graphical user interface? I want to change the value of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- In the classify dialog, just click the name of the classifier next to the choose button, and a dialog with the parameters will be displayed.

Its not very intuitive, because it isn't a button you push to get the parameters dialog, rather its the label with the classifier name and parameters *next* to the choose button.